# WCF FederatedAuthentication session state messes with ClaimsAuthorizationManager

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-3, session, wif, federated-identity

**Context:**

There are a few threads here on Stack and on Bing that talk about [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx) and session sharing with [ASP.NET](http://www.asp.net/). None satisfy my issue fully. So here goes:

I have an [MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) site which also has a few services in the [RouteTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routetable.aspx) under the path "/services". This all works really nice. I can call Controller actions and WCF service methods both.

I have enabled [WIF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx) and [Federated Authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federated_identity) with the [Windows Azure Access Control Service (ACS)](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/features/accesscontrol/). This also works nicely. I can login using Facebook, Google etc. and a session is clearly established on my site. I can call the MVC controller actions and the WCF methods. Inside the body of those the IPrincipal for the current user is set to my current session.

Now I want to be a good boy and use a custom [ClaimsAuthenticationManager and a custom ClaimsAuthorizationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee748497.aspx). A weird problem now occurs:

---

**The setup:**

For this scenario I am logged in. I have a session. I can confirm this inside of the method bodies of my MVC controller methods and my WCF service methods. This means we can leave the custom ClaimsAuthenticationManager out of this since it is not being touched when I already have a session.

It's the custom ClaimsAuthorizationManager which causes my headache.

When I make a call to the MVC site I am authenticated with my session inside of the ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess method AND also inside of the body of my MVC controller actions. So far so good.

---

**The problem:**

When I make a call to the WCF services I am NOT authenticated with my session inside of the ClaimsAuthorizationManager.CheckAccess method but I am authenticated (suddenly) as I hit my breakpoint inside of the WCF service method.

This just does not make any sense! It seems my session is not inflated inside of the ClaimsAuthorization manager but further down the pipeline when I hit my own WCF code the session is in place!

How can this be?

Cheers,

Magnus

Comment: Can you show the config where you specify your ClaimsAuthorizationManager class?

Comment: <!-- Used to grant access for a user to the sytem. Modifies the user principal. -->
<claimsAuthenticationManager type="AzureContrib.WindowsAzure.AppFabric.ACS.InjectedClaimsAuthenticationManager"/>
<!-- Check access to a specific resource on the system for the current user. -->
<claimsAuthorizationManager type="AzureContrib.WindowsAzure.AppFabric.ACS.InjectedClaimsAuthorizationManager"/>

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that this is a configuration problem. Either my WCF authentication is not right or there is a probklem with the ASP.NET app and the WCF services are not playing nicely together.

Answer (score 0):

It might be the Stackoverflow's problem, but when I copied your config into notepad++ I saw some junk characters in the AuthenticationManager type value:[image].

As the rest of the question goes, do you have `<clear />` element before the elements that you show here?